# Solr phrase query issue for WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory

Tags: indexing, solr, lucene

When we index in Solr a field 'myfield' with value '1a b2', we are finding some unexpected behaviour.

Querying with a simple query, myfield:(1a b2), gets hits on documents that we want.

But when using a phrase query, e.g., myfield:"1a b2", we unexpectedly hit nothing.

Our schema is as follows:

```
    <fieldType name="full_ci" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="100">
       <analyzer type="index">
           <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
           <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory"
                   generateWordParts="1"
                   generateNumberParts="1"
                   catenateWords="1"
                   catenateNumbers="1"
                   catenateAll="1"
                   splitOnCaseChange="1"
                   preserveOriginal="1"
                   splitOnNumerics="1"
                   stemEnglishPossessive="1"
           />
           <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
       </analyzer>
       <analyzer type="query">
           <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
           <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory"
                   generateWordParts="1"
                   generateNumberParts="1"
                   catenateWords="1"
                   catenateNumbers="1"
                   catenateAll="1"
                   splitOnCaseChange="1"
                   preserveOriginal="1"
                   splitOnNumerics="1"
                   stemEnglishPossessive="1"
           />
           <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
           <filter class="solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory"/>
           <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
       </analyzer>
   </fieldType>
   <field name="myfield" type="full_ci" indexed="true" stored="false" required="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

Our synonyms.txt files contains this information:

```
one,1
i,1
two,2
ii,2
```

Looking in the Solr admin analysis page, we can see how the value was indexed as shown in the diagram. The WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory seems to make "b2" appear in position 3, which we guess is why our phrase query "1a b2" does not get a hit (because in this phrase, b2 is in position 2?).

If we change our phrase query to "1 a b 2" or "1 a b2", then we do get a hit, which makes sense according to the Solr admin analysis page. But a user wouldn't type this in.

[image: Solr analysis print screen]

Does anyone know how we can get our exact phrase query of "1a b2" to hit? And can anyone shed any light on what we are doing wrong

Thanks!

Comment: This works as expected with `<luceneMatchVersion>7.3.0</luceneMatchVersion>` set at least. Indexed content `foo 1a b2 bar` results in a hit when searching `content:"1a b2"`. Do you have any synonyms applied?

Comment: Hi @MatsLindh Thanks!, Checking our synonyms file, there were indeed some relevant parts. We updated the question to show this. When we removed these synonyms, we get the expected behaviour -- but for us, the synonyms are important for other things. Is there a way to make it work whilst keeping synonyms?

Comment: According one of the threads at [solr-user - SynonymGraphFilter w/WordDelimiterGraphFilter](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Solr-6-4-new-SynonymGraphFilter-help-for-multi-word-synonyms-td4318472.html), the SynonymGraphFilter can't take the output from another graph filter as its input directly. My best result came after moving the FlattenGraphFilter to after the WordDelimiterGraphFilter, and then drop it after the synonymgraphfilter (if I understand correctly, it's only necessary when indexing as the last item). Confirm that it doesn't break anything else.

Comment: .. also remember that you can use multiple fields with different definitions, so you can have a field with synonyms and one without; at least that will give you phrase matches without synonyms if necessary

Comment: Hi @MatsLindh, thank you very much for your help, I Moved the order and It solved the problem. I will Answer the question with the final solution based on your help.

Comment: Since you deleted your answer - did it give the wrong set of documents for a particular query?

Comment: Hi @MatsLindh, Yes, unfortunately we found some other edge cases which didn't produce the desired results. Thank you for the solr-user group link, this prompted us to look more there and we found this question, which looks to be very similar to ours: 

http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/SynonymGraphFilterFactory-with-WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory-usage-td4373974.html

In summary, they say you can't combine the output of Graph filters and there's an outstanding Jira for this. We followed their solution, where we use the old deprecated WordDelimiter and Synonym filters, and it now works!

Comment: Should we resolve this issue pointing to the solr-user group discussion (even though the solution uses deprecated filters)?

Comment: Do you have a few examples (constructed) of the edge cases that caused the problems? I'd just leave it as it is for now, until it can be solved using the current filter versions.

Comment: Hi @MatsLindh, This example fail "123 A5B1 abc", also this one with partial search containing dash, I indexed "abc-3-abc abc" and searched for "3-abc abc". Thank you very much for your help!!!!

Comment: I believe that there is an issue with the GraphFilter factories that prevents more than one being used in an analysis chain. I hope that gets addressed soon. I also believe that FlattenGraphFilterFactory should be used on the index analyzer not the query analyzer